# FMDatabase incremental vacuum

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

How do I implement incremental vacuuming of a SQLite database using FMDatabase?

The equivalent in pure sqlite would be to prepare the statement "PRAGMA incremental_vacuum", sqlite_step in a loop for some batch size, and finalize the statement. Then repeat until all pages are vacuumed.

How does this work with FMDatabase?

Comment: FMDB is just a thin wrapper for the SQLite API, so you can probably just do `executeUpdate` with that `PRAGMA` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was to execute this statement in a loop until batchAmount is 0:

```
[database executeStatements:[NSString stringWithFormat:"PRAGMA incremental_vacuum(%d);", batchAmount]];
```

Methods that didn't work:

- Using `"PRAGMA incremental_vacuum(:BatchAmount)"` with a parameter dictionary entry for "BatchAmount" caused a SQLite syntax error.
- Calling `executeUpdate:` caused an FMDatabase error because "PRAGMA" implies it's a query.
- Calling `executeQuery:` had no effect on file size.